# Script stops after like three minutes

Tags: php, apache, wamp, execution-time, php-ini

I have a script in php which should do a lot of calculs and compare numbers (like thousands). I dont know why but my scripts stops after like 3 min without an error message. Im sure that the scripts isnt done but stops I dont know why.

I changed the value of the

```
max_execution_time = 1800
```

in the php.ini and it still stops.

It's in local and I use wamp
Should I change some settings in Apache?

Comment: See apache logs !!! And show us script !

Comment: Did you restart the server after you made the changes?

Comment: add this to the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and this `ini_set("memory_limit","256M");` mybe you consume too much memory

Comment: yes I restart it.  My script is a bit long to show and nothing anormal in the apache logs

Comment: @Halayem Anis: did nothing changes

Comment: Is there something with apache?

Comment: i think that your problem can't be resolved in this way : use xdebug, or try to capture the code block causing the abnormal interruption, post it and after that we can help you

Comment: without error or code, i doubt anyone can help, people can only guess the issue. I will suggest you to learn how logging works and provide logs here. Share the code, people might be able to guess it by just looking at code or running it. You can try online php fiddle to run your code, to check if there is an issue with program or config.

Comment: You will find more useful information if you look in the `php error log` and not the apache error log.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have edited the correct `php.ini` file. There are 2!

The one in `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` is used by the PHP CLI and will have no effect on PHP running under Apache.

Make sure you use the wampmanager menus to edit the `php.ini` file. This will ensure that you edit the correct file.

Use this menu set

```
(left click) wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Check that `max_execution_time` is correctly set in the file that is opened by your editor. Save php.ini, then restart Apache and try your script again.